# Empty fields when I execute the select query

Tags: sql

I have table `tableq` with columns lets say; a, b, c, d, e, f. in column `f` null values are allowed of which there are some null field in column `f`.

Now I want to select a,b,c,d,e columns where `f` is null. Like this:

```
select a, b, c, d, e from tableq where f isnull
```

But it is returning empty fields when I run the query whereas there are 3 rows with null values in f column.

Comment: Can you show query which you are executing for your data fetching.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please give `space` in `isnull` like:

```
select a, b, c, d, e from tableq where f is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A,B,C,D,E from tableq where F IS NULL
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, b, c, d, e from tableq where f is null or f = '';
```

try this as well...